# Augmented reality using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, augmented-reality

I'm working in a project that consist in make a Phonegap app to use Augmented reality.
I was looking for some plugins, but most of them are not free.
someone know how could I do it? my app needs to scan a marker and when it was detected, puts with AR an image. Maybe there are an option in which I could integrate a Unity project with phonegap?

The plugins I researched were:
With pay license: 
CraftAr http://catchoom.com/product/

Wikitude http://www.wikitude.com

Layar https://www.layar.com/solutions/#sdk

without license:

ARviewer (without documentation and old version) https://github.com/dixon1e/ARviewer-phoneGap

Comment: Did you ever found a plugin?

Comment: Hi @Ben not really! we finally used Wikitude with its water mark!. I don't know if nowadays there are a new plugin going around.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I haven’t found any useable plug-in so far... too bad phonegap/cordova doesn’t have a flexible mapping to the device’s native AR suite.